# Automatically load module on system startup

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, netgear

I have a *Netgear A6100 USB* Wi-Fi adapter connected to my desktop, using the `8812au` kernel module.

However, I have to run `sudo modprobe 8812au` on every system startup.

How can I get Ubuntu to automatically load the module on startup and after system updates?

Comment: Can you try, if adding a line with `8812au` to `/etc/modules` helps?

Comment: Any feed-back on above comment???

Answer (score 2):

If adding the module to the file `/etc/modules` doesn't work, take a look on blacklist files at `/etc/modprobe.d` and search if your module was there...

you can run `grep -i 8812au *.*` at this folder `/etc/modprobe.d`
and remove or comment all the entries, add `8812au` to `/etc/modules` and then reboot.

Comment: Taking a look on blacklisted files worked for me! Thanks